# rioxarray - masks as no data

Tags: python, nodata, rioxarray

So far, I always used nodata with  the method `rio.write_nodata()`. But new raster I had several bands and I only want that pixel to be nodata, when every channel of the pixel is a no data value.

How can I archive this?

Therefore, I tried to use a boolean matrix to write a nodata mask. How can I add the matrix to the DataArray object/ or how could I add this as parameter to the `rio.to_raster` method?